# Iterative create graph with no cycles from another graph by removing edges

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, path-finding

I have an undirected graph with some edges and it is guaranteed to have some cycles. Let's call this graph G1.  I have to create another graph say G2 from this graph in an iterative fashion. I take one edge from the first graph G1 and add it to my second graph  G2 if and only if the addition of this edge does not create cycles in G2. If it creates cycle I do not add this edge. The fashion in which I need to take out edges is defined in my program logic. (Each edge has a type and we use edges of 1 type first and then second types and so on  )

So I used the normal cycle finding algorithm like https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-cycle-undirected-graph/ each time after adding the edge. If it created a cycle, I deleted the edge from second graph G2. Unfortunately its damn slow on a 5000 Node graph. What are better approaches to handle this problem?

**Information on the graph:** The edges in graphs represent complex network topology. Each edge is a data structure

```
struct edge
{
  int weight ;
  int type ;
  int verter1;
  int vertex2;
};
```

type is an enum integer

```
enum type
{
  wired , wifi , 4g , 3g , 2g ;
} ;
```

The data is not arbitrary but assigned based on some network details.  Then the processing logic requires the second graph to be created based on types. We want to first use wired lines without creating cycles. Then process wifi lines and so on.

Comment: Could you share more details about the type of edges in your graph G1 ?
Are their "type" assigned following a certain logic ? 
Or are they randomly assigned and if you need to remove an edge you remove "type 1" with a higher priority than "type 2" ?

Comment: hi @Patrick added few details in question

Answer (score 2):

You could keep some extra information while you build your second graph: the connected components in that graph.

Define an array of components. Each component is a collection of vertices that are connected by a path in the second graph. Initially, there are just as many components as there are vertices, and each component just contains that one vertex.

To quickly find to which component a vertex belongs, create a map keyed by vertices. For a given vertex, the map holds as value the component the vertex is a member of.

Whenever an edge is added to the second graph, look up in the map the two components to which the two vertices of that edge belong. When these two components are really one and the same component, the edge creates a cycle.
If not, the edge is connecting two disconnected components: in that case, for each vertex in the smallest of the two components, move it to the other component and update the map accordingly.

Comment: +1, though to make this reliably efficient, you should use a [disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) rather than literally using an array of components and a mapping from vertices to components. (With a disjoint-set data structure you get O(n) time, whereas with your data structure you get worst-case O(n²) time.)

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

Indeed, testing if a cycle is created each time you add a vertex to the G2 graph is costly. A more efficient method could consist in **using a Breadth-First Search (BFS) on your graph G1** and to **report the edges you use** to travel from a node to another when you travel G1 in your G2 **as you go along**. I recommend the second part of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bIA8HEEUxZI) for a demonstration of BFS.

**Regular BFS traversal of G1 to build G2**

I will first describe how a standard BFS traversal can help you to eliminate loops in your original graph. For your preference in removing some type of edges over others, see below.

I am going to assume that every vertex knows what its neighbors are (i.e. every vertex has some kind of list of neighbors with which they share an edge). Consider the following graph:

```
Graph1:
A------B------C
|      |
D------E
```

As we run the BFS algorithm, we will add the vertices we discover to Graph2 with the edge that was used to discover them.

We are going to start the BFS traversal of the graph at vertex A.  We color A as visited (I represent it in the graph as a lowercase character) and put it our queue of nodes to check. Since we visited A and it's our first node, I put it alone in Graph2:

```
Graph1:                        Graph2:
a------B------C                A
|      |
D------E

Queue: A
```

Now, we pick the first vertex in the queue and check its neighbors. We pick A from the queue. Node A has "B" as neighbor which is not visited yet. We color B as "visited", add it to the queue, and add it to the second graph with the edge that links it to A.

```
Graph1:                        Graph2:
a------b------C                A------B
|      |
D------E

Queue: A B
```

The next neighbor of node A is D. D has not been visited yet. We color it as visited, add it to the queue and put it in Graph2 with its edge with A. We have explored all the neighbors of A, so we remove it from our queue.

```
Graph1:                        Graph2:
a------b------C                A------B
|      |                       |
d------E                       D

Queue: B D
```

We take the next node on the queue: Node B. Node B has A as neighbor which is already visited -> nothing to do here. The next neighbor is node C which is not visited yet. We color it, add it to the queue, and add it to graph2 with its edge to B.

```
Graph1:                        Graph2:
a------b------c                A------B------C                
|      |                       |
d------E                       D

Queue: B D C
```

The last neighbor of B is node E which is not visited yet. We color it, add it to the queue and add it with its edge to node B in graph2. Lastly we remove B from the queue as we have finished with it.

```
Graph1:                        Graph2:
a------b------c                A------B------C                
|      |                       |      |
d------e                       D      E

Queue: D C E
```

Then we take the next node on the queue, D. D has no neighbors that are not already visited so it is removed from the queue. Same goes for nodes C and E. When the queue is empty the algorithm terminates.

Now look at graph2: **it doesn't have any cycles.**

To actually solve your problem, this regular BFS traversal will require some adaptations that I describe below.

**Problem (re)formulation / desired behavior of the BFS for your particular need**

Because of your preferences in edges, you will need to adapt the algorithm slightly, to explore as much as possible using the first type of edges and only use the second type (and third ...) if no other option is available.

The modification consists in starting the BFS exploration of graph1 but using only "wired" edges. When this first traversal stops (no longer any nodes in the queue), there will still be parts of the graph that you could not visit because you could not use the "wifi" type of edges. In this case you will want to recheck the nodes you have visited but using the next type of edges. If through the wifi link you are able to access a node which you could not before, you will want to resume exploring from this node using "wired" connection.

**BFS algorithm adaptation**

I can think of one way to implement such a BFS traversal. Usually, nodes to explore are kept in a single queue. When all the neighbors of a node have been checked, this node is removed from the queue forever.

For you situation I think you can use a *priority queue* to store your nodes. In this priority queue, there are 5 separate queues: one for each type of edges (wired, wifi, ...). At the beginning of the exploration, a node is placed in the wired queue. The DFS algorithm will explore this node and add the neighbors that can be accessed by wire in the "wired" queue. Then, instead of discarding this first node, you put it in the next queue, namely the "wifi" queue.

The BFS algorithm should always pick nodes in the queue of the favored edges. Only when there are no nodes in the "wired queue" will it pick in the "Wifi" queue.

One extra subtlety: when you pick a node from the the "wifi" queue, if there is an unvisited neighbor of this node over wifi, you will place this neighbor into the "wired" queue and restart BFS using this node. In this particular situation where you gain access to an unvisited node from a "lower priority" edge, you have to stop checking the neighbors of your current node as those neighbors may be reachable by wire from this first neighbor you found. Therefore you will leave the current node in its queue to come back to it later.

*I hope my explanations are clear, I am looking forward to your comments.*

Comment: I did not understand how you check that no cycles were created when adding an edge, and make this check cheaper ? this is the essence of the question. Also adding edges by certain priority can also be achieved by having the neighbors collection sorted by this priority.

Comment: I updated my answer to better illustrate how the loops are removed. As for adding edges, merely going through each node and checking its neighbors sorted by connection type is not enough. You really need to explore all possibilities with the wired connection before resulting to less preferable types. Otherwise you may end up connecting a node with a less preferable option even though it was possible to connect with a preferred type of connection. It may be a little more clear with my updated answer. Thank you for your valuable comment !

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you can adapt [Kruskal's algorithm for minimum spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm).  You're really building up a forest - a set of trees - as G2.  This is exactly what Kruskal's algorithm does. The only difference is that Kruskal's is guaranteed to finish with a connected tree. Yours may or may not depending on the nature of the edges you attempt to add.

Initially G2 is a forest where each node is a "tree" by itself.  A new edge forms a cycle if and only if it connects two nodes that are already in the same tree. When there's no cycle, add the edge. This connects two trees to form one, so compute the union of corresponding sets of nodes.

Use the well-known [UNION-FIND disjoint set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) to very efficiently track the nodes each tree, detect cycles, and do updates. Each of those operations is for all practical purposes O(1) if UNION-FIND is implemented correctly.  (There's an inverse Ackerman term in the actual time bound, but for the number of atoms in the universe, that's under 5...)

Consequently, the final algorithm will run in O(m) time where m is the number of edges that you attempt to insert into G2.

I really can't improve on the Wikipedia presentations of [Kruskals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) or [disjoint set UNION-FIND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). The cool thing is that both algorithms are very compact and easy to implement.  5000 nodes should be no problem at all. I'd be surprised if 50 million weren't straightforward for an average modern notebook.

**Added Quick Hack Implementation**
Here's some very, very lightly tested code. Seems to be working, but don't trust it for production:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct vertex {
  int parent;
  int size;
};

struct edge {
  int a;
  int b;
  int is_g2_edge;
};

struct vertex vertices[40];
struct edge edges[100];
#define ARRAY_SIZE(A) (sizeof A / sizeof A[0])

void init_sets(void) {
  for (int x = 0; x < ARRAY_SIZE(vertices); ++x)
    vertices[x] = (struct vertex) {.parent = x, .size = 1};
}

int find(int x) {
  if (vertices[x].parent != x)
    vertices[x].parent = find(vertices[x].parent);
  return vertices[x].parent;
}

void merge(int x, int y) {
  x = find(x);
  y = find(y);
  if (x == y) return;
  if (vertices[x].size < vertices[y].size) {
   vertices[x].parent = y;
   vertices[y].size += vertices[x].size;
  } else {
   vertices[y].parent = x;
   vertices[x].size += vertices[y].size;
  }
}

void maybe_add_edge(int x) {
  int a_set = find(edges[x].a);
  int b_set = find(edges[x].b);
  if (a_set == b_set) {
    edges[x].is_g2_edge = 0;
    return;
  }
  edges[x].is_g2_edge = 1;
  merge(a_set, b_set);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  srand(argc > 1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 42);
  // Build a random graph for fun.
  for (int x = 0; x < ARRAY_SIZE(edges); ++x) 
    edges[x] = (struct edge){
      .a = rand() % ARRAY_SIZE(vertices),
      .b = rand() % ARRAY_SIZE(vertices)
    };
  // Put all vertices in sets by themselves.
  init_sets();
  // Try adding all the edges to G2 in no special order.
  for (int x = 0; x < ARRAY_SIZE(edges); ++x) maybe_add_edge(x);
  // Print edges in DOT: G2 edges solid and not G2 dotted.
  printf("graph G {\n");
  for (int x = 0; x < ARRAY_SIZE(edges); ++x)
    printf(" %d -- %d%s\n", edges[x].a, edges[x].b,
           edges[x].is_g2_edge ? "" : " [style=dotted]");
  printf("}\n");
  return 0;
}
```

When I run this with 5000 nodes and 30000 edges, the run time is unnoticeable. Way less than a second.

The output is in the DOT language with G2 edges solid and unused G1 edges dotted:

[image: Minimum Spanning Forest]